# Modeling Nanotubes Geometry

Tags: geometry, physics, mathematical-physics, gcd-and-lcm, integer-lattices

In various references, we see the construction of unit cells of carbon nanotubes (CNTs) from chiral and translational vectors.

[image]

The chiral vector is given as:

$$\vec C_h = n\vec a_1 + m\vec a_2$$

While the translational vector is given by:

$$\vec T = t_1\vec a_1 + t_2\vec a_2$$

Clearly, $\vec C_h$ and $\vec T$ must be orthogonal, hence $\vec C_h \cdot \vec T = 0$. In the literature, it always appears that $t_1 = \displaystyle\frac{2m+n}{d_R}$ and $t_2 = -\displaystyle\frac{2n+m}{d_R}$, where $d_R=\mathrm{gcd}(2m+n,2n+m)$.

My questions are, how to deduce this? And how does this relate to the fact that the translational vector can determine the size of the unit cell?

I managed to replicate this idea for a hexagonal lattice, similar to graphene.

For a rectangular lattice, I successfully reproduced the chiral vector, but I haven't yet managed to understand or reproduce the translational vector (not even for CNTs, actually).

Comment: What are CNTs ?

Comment: Sorry, CNT is Carbon Nanotubes.

Comment: I think $2n-m$ (in the $\gcd$) should be $2n+m$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a matricial approach.

The given constraints can be written :

$$\underbrace{\pmatrix{C_h & T}}_{M}=\underbrace{\pmatrix{a_1 & a_2}}_{B} \times \ \underbrace{\pmatrix{n & t_1\\m & t_2}}_{C}\tag{1}$$

where $M$ should be understood as the matrix whose columns are $C_h,T$ ; same convention for the second matrix $B$ which can also be written, for a certain basis :

$$B=\pmatrix{\sqrt{3} & \sqrt{3}\\1 & -1}\tag{2}$$

Now, let us express orthogonality of $C_h$ and $T$ in a matricial way by :

$$M^TM=\pmatrix{\ell_1^2 & 0\\0 & \ell_2^2}\tag{3}$$

where $\ell_1,\ell_2$ are the resp. length of vectors $C_h$ and $T$.

Besides, using (1) and (2), we have :

$$M^TM=C^TB^TBC=$$

$$M^TM = 2 \ \pmatrix{
2(m^2+mn+n^2)  & t_1(2n+m)+t_2(2m+n) \\
t_1(2n+m)+t_2(2m+n) & 2(t_1^2 + t_1t_2 + t_2^2)}\tag{4}$$

Identification of (3) and (4) yields the three equations :

$$\begin{cases} Eq1 : \ \ \ m^2+mn+n^2&=&\frac14 \ell_1^2\\ Eq2 : \ \ \  t_1(2n+m)+t_2(2m+n)&=&0 \\
Eq3 : \ \ \ t_1^2 + t_1t_2 + t_2^2&=& \frac14 \ell_2^2\end{cases}$$

We need only the second equation which gives, as desired, the proportionnality of $t_1$ and $t_2$ with $2m+n$ and $-(2n+m)$, with a proportionnality factor $\gcd(2m+n,2n+m)$ chosen in such a way that the results are integers.

Comment: Very interesting, ty! Any special reason for choosing base B? I believe that if the system's unit cell is rectangular, to obtain the values $t_1$ and $t_2$, I need to choose another base, right?

Comment: I have chosen for unit the radius of the circumscribed circle of the hexagons

Comment: Do you know where I can find these values of t1 and t2 for a system whose unit cell is rectangular? I've looked in several places and haven't been able to find it.

Comment: I don't know, but what would be the equivalent basis vectors ? If a and b are the length and width of your rectangle, would you take$\{ (a,0) \ , \  (0,b)\}$ as the basis or $\{(a,0) \ , \ (a,\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\}$ (the second vector is the diagonal of the rectangle) ?

Comment: In the case of the rectangle, $\vec a_1 = (a,0)$ and $\vec b = (0,b)$ are the basis vectors; the idea is to obtain, for each chiral vector $\vec C_h = (ma, nb)$, a translational vector $\vec T = t_1\cdot \vec a_1 + t_2 \cdot\vec a_2$, perpendicular to $\vec C_h$, in such a way that the rectangle formed by $\vec C_h$ and $\vec T$ makes the lattice periodic, where $t_1$ and $t_2$ are functions of $m$ and $n$.